# in kotlin how to change to Array<CharSequence> from Array<String>

Tags: kotlin, charsequence

From one library module it returns some `Array<Array<String>>`, like below:

```
private val BASIC_ESCAPE_RULE = arrayOf(arrayOf("\"", "&quot;"), // " 
        arrayOf("&", "&amp;"), 
        arrayOf("<", "&lt;"), 
        arrayOf(">", "&gt;"))


fun getBasicEscapeRule(): Array<Array<String>> {
    return BASIC_ESCAPE_RULE.clone()
}
```

In the project it has dependency on that library and it also uses another library module to do lookup/translation, which only takes `Array<CharSequence>`.

```
class translator (vararg lookup: Array<CharSequence>) {

     ... ...
     fun translate(content: String) : String {}
}
```

When trying to call into a the second library's routing with the data getting from the first library,
the making of the translator `translator(*getBasicEscapeRule())`  got error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Array<String>> but Array<out Array<CharSequence>> was expected
```

In the second library it needs to use CharSequence for char manipulation.

How to convert the Array into Array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To transform an `Array<Array<String>>` into an `Array<Array<CharSequence>>`, you can use the following code:

```
val src: Array<Array<String>> = TODO()

val result: Array<Array<CharSequence>> = 
    src.map { array -> array.map { s -> s as CharSequence }.toTypedArray() }.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: Actually you don't need the `as CharSequence` as the compiler should automatically infer the type for you, but it might be better to keep it for clarity

Comment: @user2340612, well, omitting `as CharSequence` leads to a type mismatch. Seems like the compiler cannot infer the right upcast (`String` to `CharSequence`) from the expected type.

Comment: My bad, I had defined `BASIC_ESCAPE_RULE` as `Array<Array<out CharSequence>>`, that's why it was working